# mBoardButtons cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, tic-tac-toe

I am a novice to java trying to put together the tic-tac-toe app for android.
    I have the following code but keep getting errors regarding my use of a variable in the listener class. My hunch is that it is probable a scope issue but I don't know how to resolve it. Here's the complete code:

```
------------snip---------------------

package edu.harding.tictactoe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AndroidTicTacToeActivity extends Activity {

    // Represents the internal state of the game
    //a variable to make the game logic available in the Activity class - Elton.
    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    // Buttons making up the board - Elton
    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    // Various text displayed - Elton
    private TextView mInfoTextView;

    public int BOARD_SIZE = 8;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_tic_tac_toe);

        mBoardButtons = new Button[BOARD_SIZE]; //cheat by creating a local variable BOARD_SIZE.
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two); 
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three); 
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four); 
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five); 
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six); 
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven); 
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight); 
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine); 

        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information); 

        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        startNewGame(); //start a new game - Elton.

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_tic_tac_toe, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //a method to start anew game - Elton
 // Set up the game board. 
    private void startNewGame() {       

        mGame.clearBoard(); //clear the board - Elton

        // Reset all buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < mBoardButtons.length; i++) {
            mBoardButtons[i].setText("");
            mBoardButtons[i].setEnabled(true);    
            mBoardButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(i));
        }

     // Human goes first
        mInfoTextView.setText("You go first.");
        }

    private void setMove(char player, int location) {

        mGame.setMove(player, location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false); 
        mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
        if (player == TicTacToeGame.HUMAN_PLAYER) 
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 200, 0));             
        else 
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.rgb(200, 0, 0)); 
    }

}

//Handles clicks on the game board buttons
class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener { 
 int location; 

 public ButtonClickListener(int location) { //this is a constructor.
     this.location = location; 
 } 

 public void onClick(View view) { 
  if (mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled()) {
            setMove(TicTacToeGame.HUMAN_PLAYER, location);              

            // If no winner yet, let the computer make a move
            int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();
            if (winner == 0) { 
             mInfoTextView.setText("It's Android's turn.");
             int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
             setMove(TicTacToeGame.COMPUTER_PLAYER, move);
             winner = mGame.checkForWinner();
         } 

         if (winner == 0)
             mInfoTextView.setText("It's your turn.");
         else if (winner == 1) 
                 mInfoTextView.setText("It's a tie!");
             else if (winner == 2) 
                 mInfoTextView.setText("You won!");
         else 
                 mInfoTextView.setText("Android won!");
     } 
 }    
}


-----------------snap----------------------------------------



The errors I get are:

mBoardButtons cannot be resolved to a variable
The method setMove(char, int) is undefined for the type ButtonClickListener
mGame cannot be resolved
mInfoTextView cannot be resolved
The method setMove(char, int) is undefined for the type ButtonClickListener

All the above errors appear in the onClick() method of the listener.

Please help.
```

Answer (score 0):

`mGame` cannot be resolved because is not defined in the `ButtonClickListener` class but in `AndroidTicTacToeActivity`. You should give access to it from different part of you game: usually in games, you do that implementing the game state class as a singleton.

`mInfoTextView` same reason, is not part of the `ButtonClickListener` class definition so you cannot access it directly.

`setMove` as well, is a private method of the `AndroidTicTacToeActivity` class, so you cannot use it outside of that scope.

You should review carefully the design of your game and classes, maybe creating different "modules" in the overall architecture and expose the proper functions and properties to be used by other components.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do I give it access? I think the problem really is that I'm not sure about the ButtonClickListener class. Why are listeners in java declared as a class within a class. Did I do it the right way?

Comment: It's not mandatory to create a separate class like that but you can define it "inline" as in the example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html. You can then put the code of your game logic in a method and call it in the onClick.